# Dojo dialog box non draggable

Tags: dojo, dialog

I have used many of dojo dialog boxes in my application. By default dojo dialog boxes are draggable. How to make dialog boxes not draggable anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `draggable: false`.

The draggable property is listed in the [API docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dijit/Dialog) and is visible in the [source](https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/1.10.4/Dialog.js#L87).

Comment: Thanks Ken. I am trying to implement your suggestion in the code as follows  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/Dialog" data-dojo-id="myDialog" title="Share your document" data-dojo-draggable="false"> . But its not working. Can you please help me in this.

Comment: data-dojo-draggable is not a thing that exists.  If you're doing it declaratively, `data-dojo-props="draggable: false"`